# Install Xcode in OS X Tiger 10.4.11

Tags: install, xcode, macos

So I'm attempting to install Xcode on OS X Tiger on my iBook G4 (It was a gift.) I needed Xcode because I was trying to install MacPorts so that I could easily install software, namely `git`.

However, when I attempt to install it via what MacPorts says to do: http://guide.macports.org/#installing.xcode.other via the [link](http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?bundleID=19907) for 10.4, it just sits there loading… nothing happens.

Does anyone know of a better way to install MacPorts than via Xcode, because I can't download it. …or if anyone knows how to install Xcode for OSX 10.4.11, that would be great!

Comment: <strikethrough>Poke around in Apple's developer centre, I succeeded to install XCode for Tiger there. That's a while ago, though, so I don't remember exactly how I found it.</strikethrough> I just read patrix' answer.

Answer (score 7):

I had more success with downloading it from developer.apple.com directly

- Point Safari to http://developer.apple.com/
- Click on Mac Dev Center (on the left, in the OS X Mavericks box
- Sign in (or create a free account if you don't have one yet)
- In the "Additional Downloads" section at the bottom, click on "View all downloads"
- Deselect all categories besides "Developer Tools"
- Jump to about page 10 (of 11), the package is from Nov 2, 2007
- Click on "Xcode 2.5 Developer Tools"

Comment: Will try this out and see if I can't get it working!